# How can check files are duplicated with Zend Framework Form 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the zend form with four zend_form_element_file. I try to find: Do these four files that have duplicate each other?

Actually I get the file name from form, but I want use hash from file.
If I use **hash_file('sha256', 'filename.txt')**, I've got a error 'No such file or directory in'. 
Usually that file has not upload yet. ZF1 use tmp directory, but I don't know how to get it there.

```
$elements = array();
foreach ($form->getDisplayGroup('elements') as $el => $v)
{
    /** @var Zend_Form_Element_File $v */
    $elements[] = $v->getFileName();
}

if(count(array_unique($elements)) != 4)
{
    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->addMessage(array('success' => $this->tra->_('Files are duplicated!')));
    $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
    return $this->_redirect($detailsUrl);
}
```

Thanks in advance.